# Confusion with web.xml file for Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to learn Struts2. When I see the web.xml file for Struts2 in some of the sites it's mentioned as:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

and where as in some examples its mentioned as:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Could anybody please help me? What is correct and why is it there are two approaches?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FilterDispatcher](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher) it’s deprecated since `Struts 2.1.3`. It’s always recommend to use [StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Basically  `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` been introduced due to variety of reasons

1. older filter setup was confusing and led to issues
2. The new setup also was forward looking towards the OSGi plugin.
3. Better enable customizations and overrides by advanced users

for further information follow the below mentioned thread

[New filter strategy RFC Struts2](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/s2-New-filter-strategy-RFC-td3540209.html#a18045478)

Comment: +1 for an excellent explanation of the change and supporting link.

Comment: Thanks Steven, i believe it always better to explain the reason to get better idea